# Could not transfer artifact from.to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Tag mismatch

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, maven-dependency

I am getting this issue since last 3 days and I have tried almost every answer on Stackoverflow but it didn't help. So I took dependencies from one of my friend to proceed further. Now when I newly added spring boot starter data jpa dependency, I again started getting sync issues.

[image: IntelliJ error]

In my org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar path I have two folders. One is 1.9.7 which I took from my friend and other which is getting downloaded is 1.9.6 and it is having issue. From structure of both folders I can see there are somethings missing in 1.9.6.

[image: 1.9.6]

[image: 1.9.7]

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: You can start by getting rid of .lastUpdated file. Does the issue occur if you try to run Maven from the Command Prompt (for instance mvn validate)?

Comment: if I try to refresh it. I even tried to run maven from command prompt and same issue. But just now I separately downloaded the missing files in 1.9.6 from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 and added in 1.9.6 and refreshed and that issue gone. I am not able to understand what's the issue